# Task not serializable error when using map function for spark Dataset in Kotlin

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use map function with spark Dataset in Kotlin like this - `Record{value, id}`

Here is the dummy code:

```
fun updatevalue(records: Dataset<Record>): Dataset<Record> {

    return records.map(
        MapFunction { record: Record -> recordReader.updateRecord(record) },
        Encoders.bean(Record::class.java)
    )
}
```

```
class recordReader() : Serializable {
    val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RecordReader::class.java)

    fun updateRecord(record: Record): Record {
        logger.info("Inside RecordReader function")
        record.value = 100
        return record
    }
}
```

When running this i am getting task not serializable error. Can someone please help here? Thanks in advance.